# How to handle duplicate row with join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table bic_table.

```
------------------------- 
KeyInstn  | SwiftBICCode  
100369    |  BOFAUSV1     
100369    |  MLCOUS33
```

keyInstn_table

```
------------------------- 
KeyInstn  | country  
100369    | USA
100370    | India
```

I am trying to join keyInstn_table with bic_table.

And I want to join both value as a comma separated.

How to get the result as

```
------------------------- 
KeyInstn  | country  | SwiftBICCode   
100369    | USA      | BOFAUSV1,MLCOUS33
100370    | India    | BOFH76HG
-------------------------
```

Comment: could you please provide sample of the data along with the desired output?

Comment: Use proper Markdown to format your question, not HTML tags. This code is very hard to read and not getting any better. You only seem to show *one* table, not two. `JOIN` means you have two tables you want to combine. Or did you mean *group* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database version is SQL Server 2017+ then you can use following:

```
SELECT a.keyInstn, country,STRING_AGG(SwiftBICCode, ', ') AS SwiftBICCode
FROM tablename a inner join keyInstn_table b on a.keyInstn=b.KeyInstn
GROUP BY a.keyInstn,country
```

Alternatively, you can use `stuff()` for lower versions of SQL Server

```
select u.keyInstn, country, 
stuff(( select concat( ',', SwiftBICCode) from tablename y 
        where y.keyInstn= u.keyInstn for xml path('')),1,1, '') 
from tablename u inner join keyInstn_table b on u.keyInstn=b.KeyInstn
group by u.keyInstn,country
```

Comment: STUFF doesn't concatenate anything. It's the XML part that isn't visible here that combines the values by turning them into XML with "empty" tags, then removing the trailing comma with `STUFF`

Comment: I have to join a table keyInst also

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos and Fahmi